# Using IIs as it I would use Apache

Tags: iis

I want to use IIS the way I use Apache. With that, I mean to, for example, create a simple html file, with only a "hello" message, put this file inside the IIS folder and then be able to access this html page thru eg.: localhost/mypage.html.

I can't figure it out how to make this. I've searched on Google, but nine has helped me.

My doubts are:
The IIS server is turned on, I saw this on the IIS Manager. So, what are the folder that I should place my html file and what are the default port that IIS uses so I can access my html file via localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new website and point to the folder where your html file resides

GO to IIS Manager->Right Click on `Sites` -> Add Website

[image]

Are you getting the localhost default screen[image]

Restart Your server as whole,

[image]

See if the IIS Worker Process is running on the task manager,
[image]

Comment: ok, so I've ad a site and pointed it to the folder where my html file is. The port I used is 10, but when I try localhost:10/teste.html, nothing happens. Can you help?

Comment: So, I added a new site, pointed it to the folder where my html file is, using the port 5673 like in your image above.
so in the Chrome, I tried "localhost:5673/" and nothing appears on the screen. Also tried "localhost:5673/teste.html"

Comment: Is it working, see whether the `Start Site immediately` box is checked

Comment: Yes, it was checked. I also restarted the site...
I don't get this screen of IIS. Maybe my IIS isn't started?

Comment: Right click on your server and restart it

Comment: In IIS Manager, in Action, Manage Server, I've stopped it and initialized it again, but still nothing. 
I have xampp installed, but apache isn't initialized. Maybe thats what causing the problem?

Comment: Even I have Xampp installed,but stop the Xampp service completely,

Comment: got it! I add in Windows Features the Static Content and HTTP Errors. Now I can see my test website and the iis start page. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Omg! Pleasure is mine :-)